# How can i create custom users with only forms?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am a beginner in Django an am using version 2.2 .I created a user form to sign a user in the site but it cant add other field information to the database

I have tried adding other fields in the fields list add adding fields but nothing works`

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    get_user_model

)

User = get_user_model()


class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='PUsername')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email address')
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label='Confirm Email')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,label='Password')
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,label='ConfirmPassword')
    age = forms.CharField(label='your age')
    info = forms.CharField(label='info about you')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'email2',
            'password',
            'password2',
            'age'
            'info'
        ]

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email2 = self.cleaned_data.get('email2')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if email != email2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Emails must match")
        email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must match")
        email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if email_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "This email has already been registered")
        username_ex = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if username_ex.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This username is taken")
        return super(UserRegisterForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,get_user_model,login,logout


from .forms import CreateUserForms
import random
import string



def register_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        frm=CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if frm.is_valid():
            username, email, password = frm.cleaned_data['username'], frm.cleaned_data['email'], frm.cleaned_data['password1']
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            new_user.is_active = True # if you want to set active
            new_user.save()
    else:
        frm=CreateUserForm()
    return render(request,'registration/signup.html',{'form':frm})

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

Expected results are the working form,but actual results are only saving   the username, password and email

Comment: Django is beautiful. why don't you try [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/). Less clutter and much more readability.

Comment: You haven't customised the `User` model, the default Django `User` model that you're saving doesn't have an `age` or `info` field. So how do you expect that to be saved? You need to [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) to learn how to extend the default `User` model with a `UserProfile` for example or [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) to substitute with your own `User` model so that the fields are saved directly on the model.

Answer (score 0):

read the documentation on python super . you are using it in wrong way. calling super at last of the clean method mean it it execute the modelform clean method and code before super get modified .

Comment: this is correct, but has nothing to do with the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question is

> How can i create custom users with only forms?

The answer to that is: That's not possible. Whatever you want to save to the database, you have to have a corresponding model for it. Forms only determine what data is submitted by the clients and how that data is processed.

So if you want to save columns `age` and `info` for your users, you'll have to create a `Model` and the corresponding table and columns in your database to hold these values.

Now, the default Django `User` model only takes `username`, `email` and `password` (plus some booleans like `is_staff`, `is_superuser`, `is_active` etc...). If you want to save additional information, you have a few options that are well described in the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#customizing-authentication-in-django), either by extending the default `User` model or by substituting it.

The recommendation when starting a new Django project is to always at least substitute with your own `User` model (see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)). If you will only ever have one type of user, then add the `age` and `info` fields on your custom `User` model. But if there's any chance that you might have different types of users where `age` and `info` might not be relevant in the future, extend your custom `User` model with a profile.